# Edited: Grep/Awk- Print specific info from table

Tags: regex, shell, unix, awk

(This example is edited, following a user's recommendation, considering a mistake in my table display)

I have a .csv table from where I need certain info. My table looks like this:

```
Name, Birth

James,2001/02/03 California
Patrick,2001/02/03 Texas
Sarah,2000/03/01 Alabama
Sean,2002/02/01 New York
Michael,2002/02/01 Ontario
```

From here, I would need to print only the unique birthdates, in an ascending order, like this:

```
2000/03/01
2001/02/03
2002/02/01
```

I have thought of a regular expression to identify the dates, such as:

`awk '/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]/{2}/' students.csv`

However, I'm getting a syntax error in the regex, and I wouldn't know how to follow from this step.

Any hints?

Comment: Escape slashes. Or simply print Field 2 values if there are more than two fields, something like `awk 'NF>2{print $2}' students.csv`

Comment: In your real data are the names really just 1 word? You're getting answers that assume the answer to that is "yes" so please fix your example if that's not the case.

Comment: Yes they are just 1 word.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`cut`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) and [`sort`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html) with `-u` option to print unique values:

```
cut -d' ' -f2 students.csv | sort -u > out_file
```

You can also use `grep` instead of `cut`:

```
grep -Po '\d\d\d\d/\d\d/\d\d' students.csv | sort -u > out_file
```

Here, GNU [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) uses the following options:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.
`-o` : Print the matches only (1 match per line), not the entire lines.

**SEE ALSO:**
[perlre - Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `gnu awk` solution to get this done in a single command:

```sh
awk 'NF > 2 && !seen[$2]++{} END {
PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"; for (i in seen) print i}' file

2000/03/01
2001/02/03
2002/02/01
```

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk and whether your names have 1 word or more and whether blank chars exist after the commas or not:

```
$ awk -F', *' 'NR>1{sub(/ .*/,"",$2); print $2}' file | sort -u
2000/03/01
2001/02/03
2002/02/01
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work in any `awk` though.

```
awk '
match($0,/[0-9]{4}(\/[0-9]{2}){2}/){
  arrDate[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]
}
END{
  for(i in arrDate){
    print i
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                   ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/[0-9]{4}(\/[0-9]{2}){2}/){    ##using match function to match regex to match only date format.
  arrDate[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]    ##Creating array arrDate which has index as sub string of matched one.
}
END{                                    ##Starting END block of this awk program from here.
  for(i in arrDate){                    ##Traversing through arrDate here.
    print i                             ##Printing index of array here.
  }
}
'  Input_file                           ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```